How to omit special characters from a string in Freemaker
I am sending a personalised HTML email for a customer on a ClickDimenions Microsoft Dynamics database and looking to omit special characters from a First Name field, for example if someone had a name of %%John%% as their first name it would be outputted as John.
My basic freemarker code is below which works to insert a First Name field and captilize the first letter (this works fine)
${"${Recipient.contact.firstname[0]}"?capitalize}
Whilst on the topic of my code can anyone confirm whether the conditional statement below using "??" will work to use Customer for any First Name field that isn't filled in. (this works fine but I can't test it because the database doesn't allow for blank entries - but i'm thinking there could be instances so would rather have it in place)
<#assign firstname=Recipient.contact.firstname[0]!""/><#if firstname=="??">Customer<#else>${"${Recipient.contact.firstname[0]}"?capitalize}</#if>

To sanitize the name by removing special characters like %% around the name, you can use the FreeMarker replace method.

@liaifat85 do you have a suggestion as to how to get this particular instance to work? Testing it i have '${"${Recipient.contact.firstname[0]}"?capitalize?replace('%', '', 'r')}' which does work to omit the % in this example but it un capitalises the first letter of the name.

I don't follow what the ?? thing tries to achieve. If the user can leave the first name empty, then it should be just NULL in the database. Using ?? in the database as a workaround is quite unexpected and confusing (for others, and for the future you). Also, if you have doubt related to the template language itself, you can try pieces here: https://try.freemarker.apache.org

So I may have found a solution to my own question—but please feel free to pick holes in it as the conditional statement for an empty “First Name” field remains untested.
<#assign firstname=Recipient.contact.firstname[0]!""/><#if firstname=="??">Customer<#else>${"${Recipient.contact.firstname[0]}"?replace("[^\\w]|_", "", "r")?capitalize}</#if>


${"${Recipient.contact.firstname[0]}"?replace("[^\w]|_", "", "r")?capitalize} can be simplified to ${Recipient.contact.firstname[0]?replace("[^\w]|_", "", "r")?capitalize}, since firstname[0] is already a string. Also, you already have that in the firstname variable, so it can be further simplified to ${firstname?replace("[^\w]|_", "", "r")?capitalize}.

Also, your example fail to parse because \w is not a valid escape in string literals. So either write ?replace(r"[^\w]|_", ..., or ?replace("[^\\w]|_", ....

Thanks @ddekany this is really helpful, going to look to simplify my code but before I do, i just want to test the workings as it currently does work however I've run into another issue. using ?replace("[^\w]|_", "", "r") is replacing all special characters and emoji's with nothing, however it's also replacing characters like é and ô which are needed, so I assume ideally i'd need something like [A-zÀ-ú] but the opposite of it?

Regarding handling "é" etc., that's a Java regular expression question (see the Javadoc of java.util.regex.Pattern). But what you probably want is ?replace(r"[^\p{javaLetterOrDigit}]", "", "r"), where \p{javaLetterOrDigit} behaves like Character.isLetterOrDigit(char).
